# Cortex-M3 NVIC_EnableIRQ(Systick_IRQn) causes hard fault exception

Tags: microcontroller, cortex-m

I'm using a Cortex-M3 LPC1548 from NXP with uVision IDE.

In the `main()` function, if I use:

```
SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock * SYSTICK_INT_FREQ); 
NVIC_EnableIRQ(SysTick_IRQn);  // <--- HardFault happens in this line.
```

I got a HardFault exception everytime.

However, if I remove the `NVIC_EnableIRQ(...)` like this:

```
SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock * SYSTICK_INT_FREQ);
```

code runs fine.

Does anyone knows why enabling Systick interrupt causes a HardFault?

I've done this before in a Cortex-M0 and never had problems.

Comment: how do you have implemented interrupt handler for systick ?

Comment: can you step code by instructions inside NVIC_EnableIRQ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What needs to be very clear here is that `NVIC_EnableIRQ()` can only be used to enable/disable **exceptions numbers** with values greater than 16.

Exceptions with numbers greater than 16 are called *interrupt inputs* while below 16 are *system exceptions*.

That means that the system exceptions listed below (example for Cortex-M3) cannot be used with `NVIC_EnableIRQn()`:

- 1 Reset
- 2.NMU
- 3.HardFault
- 4.MemManage Fault
- 5.Bus Fault
- 6.Usage Fault
- 7-10. Reserved
- 11 SVC
- 12 Debug Monitor
- 13 Reserved
- 14 PendSV
- **15 Systick**

So, the Systick Interrupt should never be activated using `NVIC_EnableIRQ` because it's an system exception. If one is using the CMSIS function `SysTick_Config()` no interrupt activation is needed since this function takes care of activating the Systick interrupt.

**P.S.** Information was taken from the excelent book from Joseph Yiu, The Definitive Guide to ARM Cortex-M3 and Cortex-M4 Processors and by analysing the function `NVIC_EnableIRQ()`.

Answer (score 2):

`Systick_IRQn` is a negative value, you cannot use `NVIC_EnableIRQ()` with Systick. The out-of-bounds register access probably causes your hardfault.

The systick interrupt is enabled as soon as the corresponding bit in `Systick->CTRL` is set.

However, `NVIC_SetPriority()` supports `Systick_IRQn` among others like `PendSV_IRQn`.

Comment: Thanks @Turbo for your answer. That helped me understand the problem and go deep in understanding this problem. Check my answer to this post for more clarification.